# Dynamic entries in the detail cell component in AG-Grid?

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Let's say whatever item in the master row doesn't get selected to be displayed ( These items typically have one heading to one value ) will be displayed in the expanded section:

I'd like it to display like this:

| Master Row --- Order # -------- Location: California -------------------------------------- |

> Detail Cell:

```
              Quantity: 2
              Date : YYYY-MM-DD
              Status : Pending
```

And if the user deselected Location, then it would go to the detail cell:

| Master Row --- Order #923847293847 ----------------------------------------- |

> Detail Cell:

```
              Quantity: 2
              Date : YYYY-MM-DD
              Status : Pending
              Location: California
```

My questions:

1. Is dynamically relocating headings:value a feature in AG-Grid?
2. Is there a type of horizontally oriented AG-Grid I can use as a template in AG-Grid that's useful for 1:1 headings and values for each order?
3. Can I use conditional logic to read off detail.Data inside the **template**: to sort what gets displayed and what doesn't?

@Component({
selector: 'app-detail-cell-renderer',
**template**: ` HTML CODE HERE '})

I've read up on the [Parent/Child](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-communication/)  article but wasn't sure if it was relevant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.